# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'line' and 'line'

Tags: python

here is the code:

```
class line:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f"< {self.name} >"

print(line('te') + line('st'))
```

this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\ronil\Documents\Calculator\main.py", line 9, in <module>
        print(line('roni') + line('levin'))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'line' and 'line'
```

the code output must be "< te st >"
the class line gives new variable type and "print(line('te') + line('st'))"
needs to join "te" and "st" that has new type line

Comment: You never defined what ``+`` between two lines is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined what is the string representation of the object but you just added the objects and not their string representation. As @MisterMiyagi said you get an error message because Python is searching for the `__add__()` method in the objects and doesn't find one. Since I don't think adding the actual objects is your goal, just use `str()` to get the strings which you can then concatenate:

```
print(str(line('te')) + str(line('st')))
# < te >< st >
```

Or use the f-string notation which automatically calls the string method on objects:

```
print(f"{line('te')}{line('st')}")
# < te >< st >
```

If you actually want to add the objects define an `__add__()` method:

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        return line(self.name + other.name)

print(line('te') + line('st'))
# < test >
```